# How do you disable the sound calling makes?

Tags: steam

It happens friend of mine "call" me when I don't answer to regular chat messages. It of course is pretty annoying, and disturbes me when I am playing other non-steam games (well even steam games)

My question is simple : how do you remove/change/mute this sound? so when someone calls me, it doesn't destroy my ears ?

Answer (score 1):

You could change the [sound associated with the call](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=788893) and use a short, "blank" sound file or a very soft sound. It's probably `voice_ringing.wav`. You might have to redo this after a Steam update as [Steam requires administration rights, when installed in Application folder (by default)](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4670-IOGV-2636) and might overwrite the file. If it's installed elsewhere, it's still able to overwrite the file.

> You can replace the following default sounds.
>
> Program Files\Steam\resource
>
> voice_busy.wav
>
> voice_dialling.wav
>
> voice_ringing.wav
>
> warning.wav
>
> Program Files\Steam\Servers
>
> game_ready.wav

Another post there :

> I finally replaced the message.wav succesfully!
>
> Every time I changed the wav, and I restarted Steam, the old message.wav returned, but now, I changed it again to a much more soft sound, and set it to "ONLY READ".
>
> Now Steam can not change it back and I'm cool with my new sound!
>
> Here are the steps:
>
> - Grab a sound.
> - Convert it to wav.
> - Go to Steam/Friends.
> - Replace message.wav with the new sound. Name it message.wav again.
> - Set it to "Only read".
> - ????????
> - MASSIVE PROFIT.

Comment: worth noting that with a hack like this, you might see it changing back to the original sound file every time steam updates. or maybe only on major updates. (although this seems to be the only option)

Comment: It could still get overwritten on an update. read-only flag is more of a suggestion than a strictly-enforced rule. You could mess around with file security options to make the file truly unmodifiable by a non-admin user, but then you might run into errors when Steam does updates. It seems like this is the best option available without an actual option in steam options, but I wouldn't be surprised if you have to re-do it at least after a major steam update.

Comment: Added that, it's true that Steam requires admin rights to update iirc